# How to set certificate path in payway payment integration

Tags: php, api, ssl-certificate, payment-gateway

In application, there is a payment option for user, user can enter the credit card details, then payment can processed. I use https://www.payway.com.au/core/AboutView payway payment gateway from Westpac(one of the Australia Bank).

I just set the certificate path in `processCard.php`:

```
    $initParams =
        "certificateFile=C:/website/payment-gateway/ccapi.pem" . "&" .
        "caFile=C:/website/payment-gateway/cacerts.crt" . "&" .
        "logDirectory=C:/website/payment-gateway/log";
```

How can set above location path. When i run on server, it comes following error.

```
certificateFile=ccapi.pem&caFile=cacerts.crt&logDirectory=log
Fatal error: PayWay API Client initialisation failed: Certificate Authority file does not exist: cacerts.crt    in /home/serverusername/public_html/payment-gateway/Qvalent_PayWayAPI.php on line 202
```

I am new for payment integration, just post your solution. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.